# How to remove key file attribute and not over write files on upgrade

Tags: windows-installer, installation

I have a MSI installation that includes three components with **key files**. These components include .mdf and .ldf files. One of the three components is a mdf and ldf that has customer data, so it also has the `never overwrite` and `permanent` attributes for this component.

Our company now wants to support allowing the customer to 'move' the databases to a different directory / drive. However, when the user starts the application, file resiliency kicks in due to missing key files and adds new files to the original target location. I want to stop this behavior.

I removed the key file attribute from the .mdf file. On major upgrade everything should be OK; however, the install tries to replace the mdf and ldf database files, even with the permanent and never overwrite attributes set.

My question, is there a safe way to handle removing the key file attribute from the component without a file overwrite on major upgrade?

### UPDATES:

- I have tried to force an uninstall but this is still a problem if I force an uninstall before a major upgrade. <strike>I suspect that is because even in uninstall the component still exists.</strike> The `never overwrite` flag requires a key file, or registry key path to determine if it should be installed.
- My expectation is that the component should handle removing the key file attribute and still honor the `never overwrite` and permanent attributes. Based on tests, my expectations are wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I think I have hit a roadblock with this one. What I was forgetting is that a file needs to have the keyfile flag set for the `never overwrite` flag to work. So that is why the never overwrite doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you never actually needed "never overwrite" or "permanent" because whether a file stays on the system or not is managed using ComponentID ref counting, doing major upgrades "late" (after InstallExecute) and setting launch conditions that (for example) disallow an uninstall that isn't part of an upgrade. Also Windows Installer will not overwrite altered user data files anyway:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370531(v=vs.85).aspx

Too late now, but it's not clear why this wasn't a choice.

The general issue with your question is that you've made some changes to the MSI file that aren't fully described, and you've not said if the upgrade is early or late, so there's no way to know if what you're seeing is expected or not. You have a migration issue whatever you do because the current ComponentId is recorded on the system with those attributes, including key file, and you can't change that system state by changing them in a build of an MSI file.

To avoid repairs it's typically better to set the ComponentId to null for the files. This marks them unmanaged, so they won't be repaired or removed at uninstall. They are yours. So I'd recommend starting again with an "early" major upgrade (so you start the product in a clean state) and your DB files have a null ComponentId.  You'd need to first copy the existing files to other locations in this upgrade because if the ComponentId for the DB is not in the major upgrade it will ref count down to zero and potentially be removed or orphaned in some indeterminate state.

Something to check: sometimes files appear to be replaced because the major upgrade is "early", such as after InstallInitialize, which is basically an uninstall of all the old files followed by the install of the new product. If so, then your files aren't being overwritten, but maybe uninstalled and then installed new from the upgrade install. Doing the upgrade with a verbose log might verify that. However, given your description this shouldn't be happening.  Hopefully you are not setting REINSTALLMODE somehow to force file replacement.

It's not a good idea to allow database moving to another location. Apart from the Windows Installer repair that you've already encountered, I suspect that you will always need to know exactly where the database files are in case you ever want to back them up when an upgrade starts or update them during the install for some reason. Or another product needs to know where it is. Maybe it can be moved by an admin to a location that a limited user can't access. These opportunities for error will make things more complicated and error prone when compared to just installing the files in the recommended location, typically one of the standard data folders.

Comment: @PhilDB, Stein Åsmul, thank you for the feedback. This is an early upgrade. All files are removed first and then updated files are installed. In all of my years of doing this, I had never picked up on the ComponentID could be empty. I will explore this some. Migration will be difficult as you indicated, but I may be able to have some type of condition that handles this and does a move file action.

Comment: PHilDW, Good call about reinstall mode. I searched through the MSI and found that `REINSTALLMODE` is set to `amus` in the property table. As you know the switch 'a' forces all files to be reinstalled regardless of version or checksum.I am not sure why this was set in the first place. It was this way when I came here many years ago and never investigated it - until today.

Comment: Removing REINSTALLMODE = amus from the Property table, and removing the GUID for the component does the trick. It prevents having to have a complex migration method, and most importantly, after the user moves the mdf & ldf, resiliency doesn't kick in and install the blank db.

Answer (score 1):

MSI is a deployment technology - its job is to install the specified files to the right locations and ensure they are the right versions. The self-repair feature (or resiliency) is a mechanism to that end. You can't disable it in any rational way, but there are several ways to deal with the issue.

Once you move the installed files they are no longer tracked by Windows Installer, and Windows Installer will put the base file version back in the place where it is tracking the installed state (where you originally installed them).

1: **Blank component GUID**: It is possible to set a blank guid for an MSI component. This will allow the component to install on first install, and from then on the component is not tracked by Windows Installer at all. As far as I recall the component will never be uninstalled, and self-repair should not occur either, even if the file is missing. I will run a test on this in a second to verify. Also, after moving the files, a new upgrade install could put fresh database files back in the default installatin location though.

2: **Treat installed database files as read-only**: I think this is a much better option. You can install the database files as before and treat them as "read-only" base versions at their default installation location. Then you update your application to make copies of these installed database files to the location where your customer wants to store them - or a default location you specify.

The files at the new location will never be tracked by Windows Installer, and will hence not suffer any accidental overwriting, uninstall or reversion. You can even add a feature to your application to re-copy the read-only base database files to overwrite the ones in active use, but why would you want to do that? This would obviously delete all user created database content.

As to the location you copy the database files to. This could be anywhere, even the "My Documents" folder could work if you want each user to have a private copy of the database. However, if all Windows users should share a single, live database, I would suggest putting the files on a Windows share location (URL). You could even create such a share as part of your setup.